# Getting this Error onFailure: Malformed URL. Base: https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/, Relative: text:synthesize

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-platform

I'm making Text-to-speech app ,I got stuck on @Header problem that where to use header properly. and also where to use API key in header , I used header in both way as static and dynamic but it is not working properly ... and now I got this problem

// Command line code 
   #Body

```
      {
     "audioConfig": {
    "audioEncoding": "LINEAR16",
     "pitch": 0,
"speakingRate": 1
 },
    "input": {
   "text": "Google Cloud Text-to-Speech enables developers to synthesise natural-sounding speech                  with 100+ voices, available in multiple languages and variants. It applies DeepMind’s groundbreaking research in WaveNet and Google’s powerful neural networks to deliver the highest fidelity possible. As an easy-to-use API, you can create lifelike interactions with your users, across many                       applications and devices."
  },
 "voice": {
 "languageCode": "en-US",
 "name": "en-US-Wavenet-D"
 }
}
```

// Retrofit Interface

```
  public interface DefaultRetrofit {

@POST("text:synthesize")
Call<AudioResponseData> getResposeBody(@Body AudioRequestBody  audioRequestBody);
```

}

// MainActivity

```
 public class MainActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

CallRetro();



}


private void CallRetro() {



    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    httpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request.Builder requestBuilder = chain.request().newBuilder();
            requestBuilder.addHeader("X-Goog-Api-Key", "myApiKeyisHere");
            requestBuilder.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            return chain.proceed(requestBuilder.build());
        }
    });


 OkHttpClient httpClient = httpClientBuilder.build();
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/")
 .client(httpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();

    DefaultRetrofit defaultRetrofit= retrofit.create(DefaultRetrofit.class);


    List<String> list =new ArrayList<>();
     list.add("handset-class-device");
    Input input =new Input("This is a text to speak");
    Voice voice =new Voice("en-US","en-US-Standard-B");
    AudioConfig audioConfig =new AudioConfig( "LINEAR16",list ,0 ,1);
    AudioRequestBody audioRequestBody =new AudioRequestBody(audioConfig,input,voice);


   Call<AudioResponseData> responseDataCall= defaultRetrofit.getResposeBody(audioRequestBody);
     responseDataCall.enqueue(new Callback<AudioResponseData>() {
         @Override
         public void onResponse(Call<AudioResponseData> call, Response<AudioResponseData> response) {
             Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: "+response.body());
         }

         @Override
         public void onFailure(Call<AudioResponseData> call, Throwable t) {

             Log.i(TAG, "onFailure: "+t.getMessage());

         }
     });



}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

acording to Google
the "Service endpoint" to call is:
https://texttospeech.googleapis.com

you need to post to /v1/text:synthesize 
or
 https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1/text:synthesize

you are sending to the "Dicovery point" not the "Service endpoint"

`.baseUrl("https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/")` is referring to the "Dicovery point"

REF: https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/reference/rest/